# Fast rand() order search

Tags: mysql, performance, random

We have a table of 50k items and we display it at a search page with a random sort and 10 items per page.  We need to apply some filters.

`RAND()` with or without a seed is very slow. Note that items have three categories. The first category should be displayed first with random order, and then the second category, also with random order.

- generating a random number between 0 and max_id s not working because of pages and the previously mentioned constraints
- randomizing the records with php makes items always display at the same page

Is there a better solution to speed up this random search?

Answer (score 0):

here are few tip hopes it works

- Put indexes on your main field on which you are filtering
- reduce number of column in your select query (only use needed columns)
- recheck your Joins
- recheck your conditions
- recheck your group/having/order By clause

Comment: filters with the id and all ids are foreign keys and index.
np with the query if i removed the order by rand() , problem with randomizing

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Don't seed your `RAND()` call unless you're trying to test with a reproducible sequence of items.

This is tricky to do nearly perfectly without a lot of programming. In the meantime here are a couple of things to do.

First, try this. Instead of doing  `SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` use the following kind of subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM t
 WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id FROM t WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id FROM t WHERE category = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
  )
ORDER BY RAND()
```

This should save some time on the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10` operation because it only has to shuffle the `id` values, not the whole record. But it's not an algorithmic change, just a volume-of-data change: it still has to shuffle the whole list of `id` values.  So it's a quick patch, not a real fix.

Second, if you can write a PHP function that will generate a text string with, let's say, 100 random numbers between 1 and `max_id`, you could try this to get your first category.

```
 SELECT * FROM t WHERE id IN
     ( SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t 
        WHERE category = 1 AND id IN (num, num, num, ..., num, num)
        LIMIT 10 )
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

This will give you ten, or fewer, randomly chosen records in the named category, pretty cheaply.  Notice that you must provide many more than ten random numbers in your `(num, num, num, num)` list because not all the `num` values will be valid for rows with `category = 1`.

If you need more than one category, just use a similar query in a UNION to get the other category.

Both these approaches' performance will be improved by a compound index on `(category, id)`.

Notice there's an extra `ORDER BY RAND()` at the end of each of those approaches' queries. That's because the lists of `id` values generated by the subqueries are likely to be in a non-random order.